# Running through a list of Strings with a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, slice, indices

I want all the contents of `subplot_list` to be printed one by one however I am getting a type error of `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`. Is there a way I could bypass this.

```
subplot_list = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3','c1','c2','c3']
for i in subplot_list:
    print(subplot_list[i])
```

Comment: use: ```print([i for i in subplot_list])``` , read <https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python allows you to access the list item in two ways in `for` loop:

Here you can access item without giving index :

```
subplot_list = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3','c1','c2','c3']
for item in subplot_list:
    print(item)
```

OR with index :

```
subplot_list = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3','c1','c2','c3']
for i in range(0, len(subplot_list)):
    print(subplot_list[i])
```

Answer (score 3):

**i is already a string you want to print**

```
subplot_list = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3','c1','c2','c3']
for i in subplot_list:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
subplot_list = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3','c1','c2','c3']
for i in subplot_list:
    print(i)

#or access the elements with the help of index

for i in range(len(subplot_list)):
    print(subplot_list[i])
```